# Find a string (or a line) in a txt File Java

Tags: java, string, file

let's say I have a txt file containing:

```
john
dani
zack
```

the user will input a string, for example "omar"
I want the program to search that txt file for the String "omar", if it doesn't exist, simply display "doesn't exist".

I tried the function String.endsWith() or String.startsWith(), but that of course displays "doesn't exist" 3 times.

I started java only 3 weeks ago, so I am a total newbie...please bear with me.
thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just read this text file and put each word in to a `List` and you can check whether that `List` contains your word.

You can use `Scanner scanner=new Scanner("FileNameWithPath");` to read file and you can try following to add words to `List`.

```
 List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
 while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
     list.add(scanner.nextLine()); 

 }
```

Then check your word is there or not

```
if(list.contains("yourWord")){

  // found.
}else{
 // not found
}
```

BTW you can search directly in file too.

```
while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
     if("yourWord".equals(scanner.nextLine().trim())){
        // found
        break;
      }else{
       // not found

      }

 }
```

Comment: why put it into a list instead of checking the line directly and breaking the loop when a match was found? Like this, each time you read in the whole file, which size we don't know. Could be very inefficient....

Comment: @EdgarBoda your idea is there too

Comment: that last method, where I can search directly inside the file, how to break the loop when the line is found? it's displaying:

not found 4 times, then found, then not found until the end of the file

Comment: @user3040333 just put a `break`

Comment: @Ruchira already tried that, it somehow cancels the if statement, so it's now showing not found wether the string exists or not

Comment: @user3040333 try with debugger

Comment: @Ruchira same problem and here's the debugger console Listening on javadebug
User program running
User program finished

Answer (score 1):

use  `String.contains(your search String)` instead of `String.endsWith()` or `String.startsWith()`

eg

```
 str.contains("omar");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go other way around. **Instead of printing 'does not exist', print 'exists' if match is found** while traversing the file and break; If entire file is traversed and no match was found, only then go ahead and display 'does not exist'.

Also, use `String.contains()` in place of `str.startsWith()` or `str.endsWith()`. Contains check will search for a match in the entire string and not just at the start or end.

Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Read the content of the text file: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=42

And after that just use the `textData.contains(user_input);` method, where `textData` is the data read from the file, and the `user_input` is the string that is searched by the user

**UPDATE**

```
public static StringBuilder readFile(String path) 
 {       
        // Assumes that a file article.rss is available on the SD card
        File file = new File(path);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        if (!file.exists()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("File not found");
        }
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

       return builder;
    }
```

This method returns the StringBuilder created from the data you have read from the text file given as parameter.

You can see if the user input string is in the file like this:

```
int index = readFile(filePath).indexOf(user_input);
        if ( index > -1 )
            System.out.println("exists");
```

Comment: instead of textData, should I put the name of the file? for example

File file = new File(); then put "file" instead of textData ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [`Files.lines`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines(java.nio.file.Path)):

```
try(Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("...")) ) {
    if(lines.anyMatch("omar"::equals)) {
  //or lines.anyMatch(l -> l.contains("omar"))
        System.out.println("found");
    } else {
        System.out.println("not found");
    }
}
```

Note that it uses the UTF-8 charset to read the file, if that's not what you want you can pass your charset as the second argument to `Files.lines`.