# How do I read the delivery date from Edifact d96a .txt-file?

Tags: java, edi, edifact

I have a problem retrieving the delivery date from .txt-file sent with EDI.

My customers have to opportunity to set the line in a .txt-file:

*'DTM+76:**20160702**:102*

when they order something from the website to set delivery date for future deliveries.

I want to get the date (in this case 2016-07-02) and set it to the deliveryDate-variable (and then set it in the database).

I am thinking about using Scanner in java to see if the file contains the text "DTM:76" and then read the date-part of the line like [Find a string (or a line) in a txt File Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20418319/find-a-string-or-a-line-in-a-txt-file-java) . Is it possible/effective with EDI or is there a better way to do it?

The best solution for me would be something like this:

```
    if (DTM+76:YYYYMMDD::102 exists)
            {
                //set the deliveryDate by getting only YYYYMMDD from DTM:76:20160702:102
                deliveryDate= get..("20160702");
            }
```

Info about EDI and delivery dates: http://www.gs1.org/sites/default/files/docs/eancom/ean02s4/part2/insdes/053.htm 
https://www.stylusstudio.com/edifact/D96A/ORDERS.htm

Any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest using `Smooks` or `EDIReader` parsing libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we parse EDIFACTs, we split the EDIFACT into segments, then elements, then components using regular expressions like so:

```
String edi = "UNH+..."; // full edifact as string here

// split EDIFACT string into segments
String[] segments = edi.split("(?<!\?)'");

// loop through segments to find one beginning with DTM+
// lets assume its 3rd segment in array
String dtmSegment = segments[2];

// split DTM segment to get its elements
String[] dtmElements = dtmSegment.split("(?<!\?)\+");

// get date, time, period element
String dtmElement = dtmElements[1];

// split dtmElement to get date/time/period components
String[] dtmComponents = dtmElement.split("(?<!\?):");

// get date/time/period component value
String deliveryDate = dtmComponents[1];
```

Note: that when the full EDIFACT is split into segments, the segment delimiter `'` is removed from each segment String. The same applies when splitting elements and components into individual Strings.

Comment: What do you mean with full edifact as string here? I get the edifact as a .txt-file in a folder via ftp

Comment: In your case, you would parse the .txt file content into the `edi` String variable which you would then do the `.split()` on.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using pattern matching with regex, to match for the occurance of a valid line i.e. DTM+76: followed by a valid date format.

See JDoc:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Now, if a match is found you can easily obtain the date part of the match (trailing the : char) then add it to DB.